# Distribution equivalent to density?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

If I show that $(X,Y)$ has the same distribution as $Z = T\left((X,Y)\right)$ for some map $T$, and Z has density $g$, can I conclude that $(X,Y)$ also has density $g$?

Specifically, I have shown that $Z$ has density $g(x,y) = g(0,\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$ and would like to conclude that the same relation holds for the density of $(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that for each Borel subset $B$ of $\mathbb R^2$, 
$$ \mathbb P\{(X,Y)\in B\}=\mathbb P\{Z\in B \}= \int_B g(x,y)\mathrm d\lambda_2(x,y),$$
where $\lambda_2$ denotes the two dimensional Lebesgue measure, hence $(X,Y)$ has density $g$.

It actually follows from the fact that if two random variables have the same distribution and one has a density, then the other distribution also has a density.